# EF Core Include()\ThenInlude() add only one entry to each collection item

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Building ASP.NET Core API that expose data from existing db.
All required entities based on data from few tables, so created a view for each.
API output - JSON with entities hirerachy, created using includes between DbSets.

There is parent entity **Projects**, which includes child **Components**, which includes **Users**, and some more, but they are not part of the porblem. Simplified DTOs:

```
    public class RrojectDTO
    {
        public int projectId { get; set; }
        public string componentCode { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ComponentDTO> componentsArray { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class ComponentDTO
    {
         public Guid componentId { get; set; }
         public virtual RrojectDTO Project { get; set; }
         public string componentCode { get; set; }
         public virtual ICollection<UserDTO> usersArray { get; set; }
         ...
    }

    public class UserDTO
    {
         public int userId { get; set; }
         public virtual ComponentDTO Component { get; set; }
         public Guid componentId { get; set; }
         ...
    }
```

Here is how DBContext class looks like:

```
public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
   : base(options)
    {
        ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTrackingWithIdentityResolution;            
    }

    public virtual DbSet<ProjectDTO> Projects{ get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ComponentDTO> Components { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UserDTO> Users { get; set; }
    ....


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectDTO>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(f => f.componentCode);
            entity.ToView("ProjectsArrayView", "LAB");
            entity.HasMany(p => p.componentsArray).WithOne(t => t.Project)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.componentCode);

        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ComponentDTO>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(f => f.componentId);
            entity.ToView("ComponentArrayView", "LAB");
            entity.HasMany(p => p.usersArray).WithOne(t => t.Component)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.componentId);
            ....
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserDTO>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(f => f.userId);
            entity.ToView("UsersArrayView", "LAB");
            ...
        });
```

I'm connection this entities with next code:

```
`var projects = context.Projects.Where(p => p.projectId == Guid.Parse("9C373F8F-CAB8-4914-83D9-4864B2E3E7B3")).Include(co => co.componentsArray).ThenInclude(j => j.usersArray).ToList();`
```

Originally there is more includes to project, but other seems to be working fine. While one on the example does not work as expected, for example: there is one project, that have 3 components, same 2 users(User1 and User2) are working on each component, If you query each dbSet by key parameters, you should be able to see correspondent data. **project** output: 1 project -> with 3 components -> **each component contains only 1 user instead of two.**

My question is: **Why .ThenInlcude() is adding only User1 per component, but ignoring User2 ? what am i missing here ?**

If I query only components DbSet and Include(x=> x.usersArray) - result still the same, User1 per component. Also, if I'm adding User3, User4 - it is still User1 that populated.

When i found query via SQL profiler, it did contained both users (can't share query due to policies).
Went over like 20 articles, but I think I'm missing something basic here, please let me know if i can add something to make this qeustion better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a relational database. Each deep level record should have keys all the previous levels. I don't see how your User related to Component.  Add to your class UserDto componentId foreign key if each user can can work only at one component or create UserComponent table containing userId and componentId to keep many-to-many relation.

```
public class UserDTO
    {
         public int userId { get; set; }
         public int componentId {get;set;}
         public virtual ComponentDTO Component { get; set; }
         public Guid projectId  { get; set; }
         ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I messed-up a bit, UserDTO does not have "projectId", it's a "componentId" that is foreign key. Corrected in the question.

Comment: But It  means each   user can work at only one component.  Is it true?

Comment: Actually no, each component can be processed by N users. This is what I'm trying to achieve here and this is why i build one(component) to many (Users) relations. Am I mistaken somewhere ?

Comment: Yes, As I told in my answer you then should have one more table -UserComponent keeping userId and componentId

Comment: Thank you a lot! I just realized that I was looking only on one side of it and didn't realized that it should be many-to-many.

Comment: You are welcome. My advice is to create the extra table using management studio. Add autoincrement primary key to this table too since EF doesn't like tables without primary keys, After this use "EF Core Power Tools" to create code-first EF from DB.

Comment: I'm new here so can't move to the chat yet. One more question, is there a proper way to replace this extra table with a view ? customer avoiding adding new tables, but i can creaste as much views as i need to

Comment: Sorry but no way,  view can't save records .  For example, you can programmaticaly create component object in the computer memory and programmaticaly add list of user objects  to this. But after this  you have to  save it to DB and you need a table to keep several users Ids for eah componentId.  Since it is a relarional DB  you will have several records with the same componentId but different UserIds and on the contrary if one user can have several components too.

Comment: Sorry but what table do you use to keep User last and first name for example?

Comment: There is separated client-server application working with this data (CRUD). API that I work on - is meant for convinient data retrival, that it, no data modifications will be done, this is why I was talking about view, it wil be the source of relations

Comment: Sorry this is why I was wondering  what table do you use to keep User last and first name for example

Comment: I'll figure it out from here. Thanks again, you saved my day =)

Comment: Why I am asking this is  maybe Db keep user data not in UserDTO but in another DTO then you will not need to add any extra tables. Please answer this question. It's very important.

Comment: If it is working already for CRUD then you have this UserComponent relations table already otherwise CRUD will not be working or DB is not normalized. May you have to figure which table keeps userid and componetId.

Comment: So as I said, there is another sofware that work with DB, and data kept in correspondent tables, that have pretty week set of relations. Customer does not want to make changes to table structure in scope of API that I'm working on. So all the DTO in my API are loaded from veiws, like: entity.ToView("ComponentArrayView", "LAB"). This DTO should be one way - to get data from DB, format them properly send out JSON. In tables structure there is mo "UserComponent ", User -> Projects -> Components, since data orginized a bit different from what I have on my level. Hopes this clears the questions.

Comment: I am wondering who was creating this EF Dtos? You or somebody else?  If you use this data only for queries do you think that maybe it would be easier to get this data directly from SQL server using stored procedures  or functions?

Comment: I created this DTOs. Approach that you suggested was executed before, using .Net. But design had gaps, so there were a lot of issue with that aproach, as a result i was set with the task to move to .Net core and process data as seperated entities, so it can be user to form few kinds of outputs.